# Clearing std::map inside map

Tags: c++

I have a question, if i cleared map1, it will also clear map2 or there will be memory leaks? here is the code.

```
struct mystruct
{
std::map<int, double> map2;
};

std::map<int, mystruct> map1;
map1.clear();
```

Thanks.

EDIT: if no memory leaks then both map1 and map2 will be cleared when i clear map1 ?

Comment: No memory leaks in the above snippet. You aren't using `new` to start with nor are you using circularly dependent smart pointers.

Comment: thanks for fast answer, I edited the question can you take a look please.

Comment: When you write `map1.clear()`, then `map1` will be cleared. Meaning the elements inside it are removed. I think you're confusing `map1` and `map2`. Note, `map2` is a data member. When the object of type `mystruct` goes out of scope(or destroyed) then the data member will also be destroyed. You don't have to worry about memory leak here.

Comment: No `map2` will exist after `map1` is cleared. But (like everyone else) there are no memory leaks here.

Comment: @BadrTimo Also (this seems to be where you are confused). There will be no memory leaks even **without** clear. You don't have to clear maps to avoid memory leaks, they look after their own memory.